# System of linear equations with multiple solutions (R, rSympy)

Tags: r, linear-algebra, sympy

I need to solve a system of linear equations that has more variables than equations and therefore does not necessarily have a single solution. I can present the problem as matrix of unknown variables with known row and column sums like here:

```
        X1      X2      X3
 Y1     V11     V12     0
 Y2     V21     V22     V23
 Y3     V31     V32     V33
```

Xs and Ys are the known column and row sums, respectively and Vs are yet unknown variable values, which all are positive integers. For this system there will be multiple solutions, but for my problem they aren't likely to be too many.

So my question is that what would be the way to obtain all the possible solutions? I'm using R and just recently found package `rSymPy` which might be of help. Feel free to suggest other packages as well.

Comment: Is your goal to simply solve a linear system with more variables than equations? Is it a necessary constraint that the solution will be positive integers?

Comment: The answer to both your questions is yes.

Comment: Then search for an Integer Programming solver for R. Note that Integer Programming problems are known to be NP-hard.